# Trying to add movie in xcode 4.6.1 but crash

Tags: xcode, video

I'm trying to add a video in xcode but it crashes: `[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string`

```
(IBAction)Play:(id)sender {

    /////
    NSString *videoUrl=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"tnween" ofType:@"mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoUrl]];
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try:

```
NSString *videoUrl=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"tnween" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:videoUrl];
MPMoviePlayerController *player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
```